# Compact Windows 10 USB Boot Fix

Tags: windows-10, boot

I have accidentally removed my system boot using the `bootrec` command on my Windows 10 laptop and now it can't see any bootable drive anymore.

Are there any compact tools that can make a bootable usb that can just run a `bootrec` command so that I can add the system drive again on my ssd? I've tried using the [Windows 10 Installation Media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) but it is so huge to download and my connection is not that fast and I am not repairing system files, I just need to run `bootrec` so that I can configure my drive again.

Comment: Software recommendation questions should be asked at [Software Recommendations Q&A](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There are smaller tools. See [this article](https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-boot-repair-software/).